# Object destructure using reduce in separate objects

Tags: javascript

I am running into a problem. I know this looks kind of messy but It shows you how my mind is working. So the problem is exiting the destructuring loop. The first average is right, but the second continues the average. This program is not efficient but I would like to know what I am doing wrong with it.  Any help would be great.

```js
const inventory = [
  {name: 'Brunello Cucinelli',shoes: [{name: 'tasselled black low-top lace-up', price: 1000},{name: 'tasselled green low-top lace-up', price: 1100},{name: 'plain beige suede moccasin', price: 950},{name: 'plain olive suede moccasin', price: 1050}]},
  {name: 'Gucci',shoes: [{name: 'red leather laced sneakers', price: 800},{name: 'black leather laced sneakers', price: 900}]}
];
var avgPriceArr = []; var target = []; var intermediateArr = [];var obj = {}; var destructuredObj = []; var intermediateObj = [];

for (var { name: designerName, shoes } of inventory) {

 for (var { price } of shoes) {
  
  destructuredObj.push(price);
  avgPriceArr =destructuredObj.reduce((accum, currVal) => accum + currVal) /destructuredObj.length;
 }
 

 var innerObj = {
  name: designerName,
  averagePrice: avgPriceArr
 };

 target.push(innerObj);

 var outterObj = {
  designers: target
 };
}
console.log(outterObj);
```

Comment: Stop declaring your variables as globals, stop initialising them with arrays/objects when that's not what they'll hold, stop naming them with an `Arr`(ay) suffix if you want to assign them a number.

Comment: Not terribly helpful. It almost sounds as if you are belittling me.

Comment: Sorry, I'll work on my tone. I just wanted to give concrete things that make the code "look kind of messy", and fixing these would help you find the mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are pushing all the shoes into one array `destructuredObj` that doesn't get reset when the loop repeats. So the first average is correct, but the next ones are still counting the previous shoes.

An easier way that doesn't require declaring all those variables is to mix `map()`, which will make your new array with `reduce()` which will make each price total. Something like:

```js
const inventory = [
  {name: 'Brunello Cucinelli',shoes: [{name: 'tasselled black low-top lace-up', price: 1000},{name: 'tasselled green low-top lace-up', price: 1100},{name: 'plain beige suede moccasin', price: 950},{name: 'plain olive suede moccasin', price: 1050}]},
  {name: 'Gucci',shoes: [{name: 'red leather laced sneakers', price: 800},{name: 'black leather laced sneakers', price: 900}]}
];

let designers = inventory.map(({name,shoes}) => {
  let total = shoes.reduce((total, {price}) => total+price, 0)
  return {
    name,
    average:total/shoes.length
  } 
})

console.log("designers:", designers);
```

Comment: Thanks,  I just could not figure out how to exit the loop so I can restart the counter.  I hate these designer[i]........ it's so hard to follow.  Thanks you answered my question.

Answer (score 2):

First, try to replace all of your `var` to either `const` or `let`. [This](https://medium.com/podiihq/javascript-variables-should-you-use-let-var-or-const-394f7645c88f) may be helpful to explain the differences.
Second, replace your for loop to [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) function to have better performance and readability.

Those may solve your problem.
Good luck!

Comment: when u will have performance issues with `forEach`, then you already should not work with javascript, until you work with `10k` items, for each is same performance, and incredibly more readable than `"for" spaghetti`

Comment: @sonnenhaft what do you mean?

Comment: @DragoomDoc99 should not care performance in such cases, `forEach` will be not bottle neck here